# LIMIT and TOP in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty huge MSSQL db, and I would like to correctly limit my rows.

The SQL I've googled around for is as follows:

```
WITH SmallerFetch AS
        (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columns) AS RowNumber
            FROM    dbo.table
        )
    SELECT  columns
    FROM    SmallerFetch
    WHERE   RowNumber BETWEEN {$offset} AND {$limit}
```

Now, this works. However, I have a bunch of filters on my client-side, and would like to not only get rows where they're between the offset and limit. I would rather like to get ALL the rows which would correspond to a query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE something LIKE '%mssql really needs a limit function%'` but still preserve my pagination abilities.

I've looked at using `TOP`, and the `TOP` within the `FROM` clause, but it has either not worked, or not returned the correct amount of rows for my search.

I am using the DataTables library for jQuery on the client side, which is directly hooked up (with AJAX) to my response(query)-script.

I know I might've probably missed something in this post, but I will answer comments and questions in regards to my question. Why MSSQL can't be as easy as MySQL is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just move the filtering to the CTE?

so something like:

```
;WITH SmallerFetch AS
(
    SELECT      columns,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columns) AS RowNumber

    FROM        dbo.table

    WHERE       something LIKE '%mssql really needs a limit function%'
)
SELECT  columns

FROM    SmallerFetch

WHERE   RowNumber BETWEEN @offset AND @limit
```

Comment: You should be president. How come I didn't think of that.